# Horizon Error 6

Tags: transactions, horizon, ios-sdk

I'm using the iOS SDK to attempt to submit a testnet transaction, but it fails with error 6, which I believe is BAD_AUTH, too few valid signatures/ wrong network.

Here is my code:

```
static func sendPayment(accountId: String, amount: Decimal, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    guard let sourceKeyPair = try? KeyPair(secretSeed: KeychainHelper.privateSeed) else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("NO SOURCE KEYPAIR")
            completion(false)
        }
        return
    }

    let issuerID = Assets.AssetType.ABC.issuerAccountID

    guard let issuerKeyPair = try? KeyPair(accountId: issuerID) else {
        print("NO ISSUER KEYPAIR")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(false)
        }
        return
    }

    guard  let destinationKeyPair = try? KeyPair(publicKey: PublicKey.init(accountId: accountId), privateKey: nil) else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(false)
        }
        return
    }

    Stellar.sdk.accounts.getAccountDetails(accountId: sourceKeyPair.accountId) { (response) -> (Void) in

        switch response {
        case .success(let accountResponse):
            do {
                let asset = Asset(type: AssetType.ASSET_TYPE_CREDIT_ALPHANUM4, code: "ABC", issuer: issuerKeyPair)!

                let paymentOperation = PaymentOperation(sourceAccount: sourceKeyPair,
                                                        destination: destinationKeyPair,
                                                        asset: asset,
                                                        amount: amount)

                let transaction = try Transaction(sourceAccount: accountResponse,
                                                  operations: [paymentOperation],
                                                  memo: nil,
                                                  timeBounds:nil)

                try transaction.sign(keyPair: sourceKeyPair, network: Stellar.network)

                try Stellar.sdk.transactions.submitTransaction(transaction: transaction) { (response) -> (Void) in
                    switch response {
                    case .success(_):
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            completion(true)
                        }
                    case .failure(let error):
                        StellarSDKLog.printHorizonRequestErrorMessage(tag:"Post Payment Error", horizonRequestError:error)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            completion(false)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("FAILED TO GET ACCOUNT")
                    completion(false)
                }
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            StellarSDKLog.printHorizonRequestErrorMessage(tag:"Post Payment Error", horizonRequestError:error)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
Post Payment Error: Horizon request error of type request failed with message: The operation couldn’t be completed. (stellarsdk.XDRDecoder.Error error 6.)
```

I swear this worked a week ago, so I'm kinda stumped here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you capture the XDR response and decode it at https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?type=TransactionResult&network=public

Comment: The transaction is actually succeeding. Must be an error within the iOS library. Here is a GitHub issue: https://github.com/Soneso/stellar-ios-mac-sdk/issues/25